# Incompatible shapes

Tags: tensorflow.js

I'm a beginner trying to train a GAN network. Found an example https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/generative-adversarial-network-gan-using-keras-ce1c05cfdfd3
In python, the example works fine, but I need to run it under NodeJS.
I rewrote it in JS - https://pastebin.com/RZt6AtZc
And I get the error

```
(node: 3988) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Invalid TF_Status: 3
Message: Incompatible shapes: [784,1024] vs. [100,256]
```

Shapes for variables

```
noise: [128, 100]
image_batch: [128, 784]
generated_images: [128, 784]
X: [256, 784]
y_dis: [256]
noise1: [128, 100]
y_gen: [128]
```

Where did I get it wrong?

Comment: There is a shape mismatch

Comment: I noticed from the call stack that the error occurs after calling the optimizer.
When changing the optimizer to sgd, this error is not present. I didn't change anything except the optimizer. Wouldn't shape mismatch happen with any optimizer?

Comment: I think shape mismatch would happen with any optimizer, might want to pop on over to https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues and see if it's a problem with tfjs.

Comment: I haven't seen anything like it, I wrote there.